# Apache Kafka Connect/Streams API for synchronising database tables

Tags: java-8, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I was reading through Kafka documentation on Connect API and trying to relate that to my problem domain. I have multiple databases which has common tables that I need to synchronise on any updates/inserts/deletes. An exmaple is this:

1) Someone updates table "order_history" in DB1 - I want the update to be communicated to DB2/DB3 etc.

2) Someone inserts a record into "purchase_order" - I want the insert to be communicated to DB2/DB3 etc. so that the same insert happens in those DB2/DB3 etc.

3) The tables will be in all the DBs - so no missing table issue there.

These are only to be done on a specific set of tables, not the entire database. What I understand from Connect API documentation is that I need to provide the following:

1) Source Connector imports data - from SQL/File system to Kafka topics

2) Sink Connector exports data - from kafka topics to SQL/File system/Hadoop FS

But then I am trying to understand how this is relevant to syncing multiple database tables on any inserts/updates/deletes - because Connect API still involves write/read on the topics - which might not necessarily what my use case is. I have also looked at Kafka Streams but it seems like an efficient tool when it comes to doing data aggregation and counter management, again not probably my use case.

Could anyone explain whether my assumption is correct, and I should still explore Streams/Connect API?

Regards,

Comment: What problem are you actually looking to solve? "I need to synchronise on any updates/inserts/deletes" could be for lots of things :) If you want straight table replication then there are DB-specific offerings (e.g. Oracle GoldenGate). If this is application data that you're wanting to share and propagate then Kafka may well help. You need to describe better *what* and *why* you want to do something, and then we can help with the *how* :)

Comment: @RobinMoffatt      It was quite clear from the questions - insert/update/delete to database (certain tables) is quite self-explanatory. The db table can have application data mixed with some other metadata. I have updated the question if that makes sense to you

Comment: Your question has changed since I posted my comment :) Let me ask a question: Why are you wanting to use Kafka at all instead of a standard DB/table replication tool? And are these the same DBs, or different technologies?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt         because we have already implemented Kafka for some messaging activities and there is no point using a new tool unless Kafka can do this with minimum effort - it's not a question of "Why" it's a question of "Can/Can't".

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use Kafka Connect to apply changes from one database to another. You would typically use a CDC tool to take the events directly from the redo/transaction log on your source database, which pushes each event to a Kafka topic. An example would be Oracle GoldenGate, or the Debezium project.

Once on a Kafka topic, you can then use Kafka Connect's JDBC Sink to push these changes to a target database.

Where this may not meet your requirement is if you want to also mirror deletes directly in your target, since usually CDC records will have a column indicating the operation (e.g. "D" for delete) and you will get a row *inserted* on the target with this value.

However, if you are looking to literally mirror a set of tables from one DB to another DB, you should be looking at a database replication tool, not Kafka.

Where Kafka fits is if you want to stream events from one place to another (and want to store delete events, than delete them from the target), with the option of using that same data to land to other targets, or drive other direct applications. This could be Kafka Streams, a Kafka Consumer - or any of the other multitude of technologies and tools out there that integrate with Kafka.

In terms of Kafka Streams this would be useful if you want to do some processing on the data you're pulling in from your source database - for example, joins/filtering/aggregation. As well as writing Java code directly with Kafka Streams, you now have the option of using a SQL-like interface on top of Kafka, with [KSQL from Confluent](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/).

Comment: Okay - if the events (insert/update/delete) are happening (in order) on DB1, DB2, DB3 for the same table, for exmaple, `table1` - and if I want to maintain the order will Kafka Connect manage to do that or do I need to use the plain client API ? Also, Debezium is not anywhere nearly as mature as Kafka - so that's not a solution.

Comment: Yes Kafka (and therefore Kafka Connect) guarantees in-partition ordering. What's your concern with Debezium? It is already used in Production at many places.

Comment: I need SQL Server connector and no one provides that even though SQL server is the most reliable and secure enterprise solution. My issue is that this Connect API is not as simplified as the basic client API and asks developers to write a lot of code which is frankly, not required. This is not a crticism, but fact. I should only provide a list of tables, target JDBC urls, and operation type (CRUD), and  Kafka should just do this - there should not be any other boilerplate coding. Currently it requires too much fiddling. This is why I would like to know if there's a viable workaround.

Comment: You are correct, developers should not have to write code unnecessarily --
 and with the Connect API you don't have to! It is a configuration-file driven API. You only need to write code if you want to _write_ a connector plugin. There is a large community of existing [Connector plugins](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/). For SQL Server you can use [JDBC Connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc), or maybe try [this one](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-cdc-mssql). There may be other commercial options too.